# Appcheck verification flutter firebase android

Tags: flutter, firebase-app-check

I saw [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/app-check/overview/) for flutter firebase Appcheck

what do I need to do in release mode with an original certificate?
because all it says is for website verification

`await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(webRecaptchaSiteKey: 'recaptcha-v3-site-key');`
I am unable to understand what to add in code for making use of app check in flutter

Answer (score 0):

I think that code is only for the web platform.

For android open your main project directory in the terminal and follow the steps below.

flutter> cd .\android\

flutter\android> .\gradlew signingReport

This will print all your keys. Find the applicable one that you want. Then, copy the SHA-256 into the correct place in the firebase console.